# New SQL Stored Procedure not showing in Object Explorer

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using SQL Server 2005 on a client site. In the past I have created stored procedures in it with no problem. The last stored procedure I created does not show up in Object Explorer under "Stored Procedures". I tried saving it with and w/o dbo.

If I try to save another new stored procedure, the name of the one that is not displayed in Object Explorer appears as an option in the "Save File As" picklist.

Comment: Right click the stored procedures tree node and click refresh? - they are not added automatically.

Comment: Maybe you're not in the correct database when you're creating the stored proc.

Comment: I found that SQL is saving the file under c:\myname\Documents\SQL Server Management Studio\Projects\. How do I save it to appear in Object Explorer?

Comment: I have clicked refresh and am in the correct database.

Comment: To create the stored procedure, I right-clicked on Stored Procedures under the desired database.

Comment: Can you actually execute it? `exec <procname>`

Answer (score 2):

It will be added to the bottom of the tree when you execute/add the stored procedure. Refresh the Stored Procedure folder in the tree for it to sort it into alpha order.

Also ensure you are creating the Stored Procedure on the database by executing the code with `Create Procedure` before the procedure name. If you then need to edit the procedure simple modify (right click the procedure in the explorer tree) and change `Create Procedure` to `Alter Procedure.`

Comment: I executed CREATE Procedure and got Command(s) Completed Successfully.

Comment: I executed CREATE Procedure again to see if I would get an error because it existed, and I did. and got Command(s) Completed Successfully

Comment: I executed ALTER Procedure and got Command(s) completed Successfully.

Comment: It doesn't appear anywhere on the listing before or after refresh.

Comment: Which database is selected from the dropdown at the top left of the screen? Is it your database or 'Master'?